# How can I view someone's comment history on GitHub?

Tags: github

It's easy to see someone's *commit* history on GitHub, at least the recent one, but is there a way to see all *comments* they've made there?

Comment: If the answer be no, then you might be able to use GitHub's API to solve your problem: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/comments/#get-a-single-commit-comment

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: ***TL;DR:*** Search at the top of Github for `type:issues commenter:<username>`

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I disagree. GitHub is immensely related to programming. What stack exchange site do you believe this question is more relevant on?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Search for `commenter:username` in the main `Github` search box.

For example [commenter:gavinandresen](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=commenter%3Agavinandresen&type=)

To see recent activity, select `Recently updated` from **Sort** dropdown

You can also narrow the search: [is:issue commenter:gavinandresen](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+commenter%3Agavinandresen&type=)

[image]

Comment: I can see comments on issues, but not comments on commits with `commenter:username` in the search box.  Is there a way to also see comments given inside commits?